# Many files and searching by recursion in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a little problem with searching files in my catalog structures. For example I have a directory "page". Inside it I have two directories: "a" and "b". Both directories contain files: a.html and b.html. How write in Perl recursion procedure which find this files and, for example, write them into screen?

In more specific. I don't know how to write "universal" path of file. For example:

```
open (FILE, "page/ (find a and b) / find (a.html and b.html)" ) or die "Can't open!";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `glob` to find the files:

```
for my $filename (glob 'page/{a,b}/{a,b}.html') {
    open my $FH, '<', $filename or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";
    # Process the file here.
}
```

See also [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aFind).

Comment: Ok, but I see that in this case I have to use {a,b,...}. But how to do it when I have for example 100 directories and want to contain all of them?

Comment: You can use `?` which stands for any character, or even `*` which stands for any string (e.g. `glob 'page/?/*.html'`).